# How do I change this list of tuples to the following format?

Tags: python, data-mining

I am trying to change the following tuple:

```
[((' "business_id": "zPBccKsIHYtLUGFNYIi8Uw"', ' "business_id": "znDUBjt-m2qmXi_p3m3rDA"'), 0.09523809523809523),((' "business_id": "zauhMY78k36XPfxD3GURkQ"', ' "business_id": "zp-K5s3pGTWuuaVBWo6WZA"'), 0.07407407407407407)]
```

to this format:

```
{'b1': 'zPBccKsIHYtLUGFNYIi8Uw', 'b2': "znDUBjt-m2qmXi_p3m3rDA', 'sim': 0.09523809523809523}
```

I tried working on this by trying to change it to dict (which is not possible because it does not know how to assign keys and values) and list but nothing seems to click.

I am currently writing the tuples into an output file using Python by:

```
fout = open(outfilePath, mode = 'w')
fwriter = csv.writer(fout, delimiter = ',', quoting = csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)


for pair in similarPairs:
    fwriter.writerow([ str(pair[0][0]), str(pair[0][1]), pair[1]])
fout.close()
```

I am finding similarPairs using Jaccard Similarity with threshold>=0.055 by:

```
## Computing the Jaccard Similarity for the candidate pairs.
similarPairs = candidatePairs.map(lambda currPair : computeJC(currPair, ratedBusinessUsers)).filter(lambda f : f[1] >= 0.055).collect()
```

How do I change my output write to get the format I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your tuples stay in that format then you need to do some string parsing in order to get the IDs out of the first element of the tuple.  `split` is the best way to do that for this case.  For your current format, this code works, but you can definitely generalize it for other cases.

```
def fix_tuple(tup):
  ids = tup[0]
  id1 = ids[0].split('"')[-2]
  id2 = ids[1].split('"')[-2]
  return {'b1':id1,'b2':id2,'sim':tup[1]}
```

In action:

```
tup = ((' "business_id": "zPBccKsIHYtLUGFNYIi8Uw"', ' "business_id": "znDUBjt-m2qmXi_p3m3rDA"'), 0.09523809523809523)
print(fix_tuple(tup))
# Output: {'b1': 'zPBccKsIHYtLUGFNYIi8Uw', 'b2': 'znDUBjt-m2qmXi_p3m3rDA', 'sim': 0.09523809523809523}
```

Answer (score 0):

from your file writing code it seems that your tuples are consistently formatted, so if that's true this is trivial:

```py
x = ((' "business_id": "zPBccKsIHYtLUGFNYIi8Uw"', ' "business_id": "znDUBjt-m2qmXi_p3m3rDA"'), 0.09523809523809523)
yy = {}
yy['b1'] = x[0][0].split(':')[1].strip('" ')
yy['b2'] = x[0][1].split(':')[1].strip('" ')
yy['sim'] = x[1]
```

you know where in the tuples all the members are, so grab the values you want, remove the extraneous quotes and whitespace, and pack it all into a dict.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import re

KV_RE = re.compile(r'"(?P<key>[^"]+)":\s*"(?P<value>[^"]+)"')
getvalue = lambda kv: match.group("value") if (match := KV_RE.search(kv)) else None

def dict_from_pair(pair):
    ((kv1, kv2), sim) = pair
    return dict(b1=getvalue(kv1), b2=getvalue(kv2), sim=sim)

pair = ((' "business_id": "zPBccKsIHYtLUGFNYIi8Uw"', ' "business_id": "znDUBjt-m2qmXi_p3m3rDA"'), 0.09523809523809523)

print(dict_from_pair(pair))
# {'b1': 'zPBccKsIHYtLUGFNYIi8Uw', 'b2': 'znDUBjt-m2qmXi_p3m3rDA', 'sim': 0.09523809523809523}
```